# How to best apply a function to a dataframe (to apply() or not)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which consists of <10 columns and many rows, its time series fluid properties.

I want to create a new column with another value derived from the function which takes two of the columns (pressure and temperature) as inputs along with two strings.

I have achieved this using the code below but it takes a long time to run and would like suggestions how to speed it up? Ideally without rewriting the function `FluidProp`.

```
df['rho']=df.apply(lambda x: FluidProp('He', x['P1'], x['T1'], 'Rho'), axis=1)
```

Comment: there are modules which try to run pandas with multiprocessing - ie. `dask`

Comment: This [article](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) might be useful